# Can I shrink a dotnet publish package

Tags: .net-core, publish

I have recently started developing using dotnet core (as opposed to old fashion plain .net) to create a number of small utility console applications.

The development is fine and it has come to the point I want to publish them.

I am using the CLI and as I am only interested in Win 10 deployments, tried

```
dotnet publish -c release -r win10-x64
```

It worked and built me a "publish" folder where everything seemed to work, though the "publish" folder is huge (~70mb) compared to the size of the app (~500 lines of code).

As I am only going to deploy to Win10 machines is there a way to package this so I don't need all the .NET files? I thought that was what the -r option was for but that does not seem to have achieved much.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/30 IL Linker is your only hope right now, while .NET Core 3.0 (in 2019) should ship a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you want to deploy your app/who is going to use them.

The `-r` flag creates a self-contained app. This causes the `publish` command to include the necessary .NET Core DLL's for the specified platform (and platform specific nuget packages if they are avaiable), which means anyone can use the app without having to install .NET Core runtime.

If you remove the `-r` flag then `publish` will only include the DLL's for you app. But this means whoever wants to use your app must first install the .NET Core runtime.

You can see the difference by using the `-o` flag to write the publish output to different directories e.g.

```
dotnet publish -c release -r win10-x64 -o ./publish-win10
```

or

```
dotnet publish -c release -o ./publish-any
```

Now go and have a look at what has been written to `./publish-win10` and `./publish-any` folders and you can the difference.

If you are installing them onto a system where the .NET Core runtime is already present then you can just distribute the DLL and save a lot of space. However if you want to be able to distribute the app without the end user having to worry about having the .NET Core runtime installed then the `-r` flag to create a self-contained distribution is the way to go, but results in the 'package' including the necessary .NET Core assemblies.

AFAIK the `-r` flag does not affect how you app is compiled, just what runtime DLL's are included as part of the `publish` command. So you always get the same DLL for your code if you publish it for `win10-x64` or with, or without, the `-r` flag so your app DLL will run on any (.NET Core compatible) platform, but I am happy to be corrected on that point.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it has helped to understand it a little better now. Removing the -r  flag does give a small release package but of course without the .exe which is going to be problematic.

Comment: I suspect I am just asking for the wrong thing and I wil eed to go with the "huge" release package for now. perhaps using dotnnet core was not the right choice.

Comment: @Simply Ged Is it normal for the project even not self contained and targeted to same machine still generate 70mb of files? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Unlike .NET 4.x which you are used to where building is the standard to create an output, .NET Core (And .NET 5) considers building and publishing to be very different.

The huge (70MB) size is because the publisher is assuming that your target does not have any form of the .NET Framework installed, so is bundling it in with your project.

You can change your publish line to

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 --self-contained false
```

Just by itself, this will create the .NET Core standard - A `.dll` (Your application), a `.exe` (That runs the application), some `.json` files for settings, and a `.pdb` file for debugging symbols.

To alter the application to the .NET Framework standard output that you are used to, open the `.csproj` file in a text editor, and below the

`<TargetFramework>netx.x</TargetFramework>`

line, add

`<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>`
`<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>`

And rerun the publish command. This will result in a single `.exe` and a single `.pdb` in the `publish` directory (The `.pdb` file which you can safely delete).

**Note**: Since you have included `--self-contained false`, the target will need the specified version of the .NET Framework (The one specified in your `.csproj` file) installed. Whilst many versions of the .NET Framework are currently installed on most Windows 10 Devices (Generally located at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework` or `C:\Program Files\dotnet\`), the .NET Core / .NET 5 Runtimes aren't yet as common (Although will likely be distributed through Windows Update in the near future), so may require a once-off download if the recipient of your `.exe` does not have it.

Whilst the .NET Core / .NET 5 resultant binaries ARE larger (Although by around 150kb - Not 50MB), they run significantly faster than their .NET Framework 4.x counterparts.

Comment: Oh, but still the file size still the same I see with multiple file output. is there anyway to reduce it more?